# WPML site reload to a different language at random

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, wpml

We just had our Website revamped, and we used WordPress with the [Multilingual Plugin](https://wpml.org/) to handle translations. Originally, we built the site on a different, staging, domain. Then we added translation, then moved the site on the main domain. Everything seems to go well, until I started to notice that, sometimes, randomly, when someone access a page, it will load and then the entire page will reload into a different language.

Anyone worked with WPML may know how I can diagnose this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: How would a translated page normally reload - with a button click or dropdown for example? What function does that action trigger & is it perhaps being called automatically (like by a testing suite or line added in the code somewhere for testing purposes)? Maybe called twice for some reason? Perhaps in the move some files/functions were duplicated that call the relevant code multiple times from various places? Does it happen only with particular pages or WP templates, or all over the place? First need to know how the expected behavior works so you can find it and ID the problem.

Comment: Unlikely. There is only one JS file, handling menus pop-overs and offcanvas. You actually need to click on a button to change the language, and there is no special widgets or anything; it's just an anchor tag per language. My guess is that the page reloads at the end of some PHP script, but I cannot diagnose it because it happens randomly and suddenly.